# how do I add global Environment Variables in Gentoo?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, gentoo

I know they get read from /etc/env.d/ but I tried adding in my own file in there (`00example`) with a single env variable but they aren't picked up after either env-update.

How does a user declare them globablly and why did my method not work?

linux 3.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=5 : you need to run `env-update` so that your file gets merged into `/etc/profile.env`.

Comment: I ran env-update nothing happened.

Comment: what about `env-update && source /etc/profile` ? Check that your variable is stored in `/etc/profile.env`...

Comment: that worked cheers - what's the reason?

Comment: maybe your `/etc/profile` is not sourced at boot... did you log in as root? Maybe `/etc/profile` is handled differently for root user... Not sure...

Comment: yes logged in as root

Comment: If the variable is not visible at startup without a manual `source /etc/profile`, even as root, it shows something goes wrong. At least not like you want it to behave. So maybe try to edit /etc/profile and add `set -x` before the `/etc/profile.env` handling stuff, and `set -x` after it... Then see what trace is given at a root login... You could put it on pastebin.com so I can have a look.

Comment: The file `/etc/profile` is only read when a login shell is starting up.  Changes to it will not take effect automatically; you need to log in again, or do `source /etc/profile` manually.

Comment: Totally agreed. The suggestion was to see whether we actually source it or not at a login shell startup. Are you suggesting that a root login is not seen as an interactive login?

Answer (score 1):

If you created the file `/etc/env.d/00example`, it would only get set when you attempt to run the command `example`. Are you sure you aren't looking for setting variables in `/etc/env.d/99local` (or /etc/profile)?

Comment: the file name has nothing to do with commands typed later. `/etc/env.d` is only used to organise **global** environment variables in several files for clarity.

Comment: maybe - what's 99local? It's not in my system at the moment

Comment: It's what the docs say to stick system wide user variables, but chickenkiller is right, the names doesn't matter, just the order that they get created/appended. Out of curiosity, what variable did you attempt to set?

Comment: also, make sure the files starts with 2 real digits (`0` and not `O` for example), the python code that parses your file is touchy about it... see https://github.com/funtoo/portage-funtoo/blob/stable/pym/portage/util/env_update.py#L63

Answer (score 0):

add `name=value` pairs to `/etc/env.d/##identifier` (where `##` are two decimal digits and `identifier` is a memorable name), then `sudo env-update` and `source /etc/profile`. see the Gentoo Handbook under "[Working with Gentoo: Environment Variables](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Working/EnvVar)".